# Advanced routes in expressjs

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I'm trying to create express route that will match both

```
/users/joe

/users/joe-4574
```

I know that I will need regular expression to solve this but having tried all-sorts of combinations I can't seem to get it to work.

**Note** : I want to match any user/userid, joe and 4574 are just examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
app.get(/^\/users\/([a-z]+)(?:\-(\d+))?/, ...);
```

This obviously assumes that the user part can only contain lowercase `a` to `z`, and that the userid part is all-digits, but I'll leave the details up to you :)

This *will* also match requests for `/users/joe-foobar`, but it will set `req.params[1]` to be `null` (because it can't match an all-digit userid).